# How find steps to Question: $x = 10^{x-1}$. Answer: $x = 1$

Tags: exponential-function

I created an equation a bit ago where I knew the answer, but not how to solve it.

Equation: $$x = 10^{x-1}$$

Answer: $x = 1$

I can not see to find any documentation related to this problem. I know that the equation can be written as $x = a^{x-1}$ and the answer will still be $x = 1$. The only reason I know the answer is because I can plug it in and I made it around the answer. I would love to know the steps behind how to solve this equation.

Comment: Don't think there are easy ways to provide a closed form solution, but there is another root in $(0, 0.5)$, which is evident if you check signs of $10^{x-1}-x$.

Comment: you can try the Newton method

Comment: There are no algebraic methods to solve such equations. You can try to plot the functions or make use of numerical methods. There is plenty of information about the latter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can rewrite your equation as

$$-x\ln 10 e^{-x\ln 10}=-\frac{\ln 10 }{10},$$
and then use [Lambert W function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) to solve the obtained equation: $-x\ln 10 = W\left(-\frac{\ln 10 }{10}\right)$. As you can read on wiki, for some values of $z$ $W(z)$ is multiply defined, hence one one branch you obtain $\forall z>0 W(z\ln z) = \ln z$, which in our case gives $x=1$. Other branches of $W$ will give other roots of this equation.